# Linktext in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

Is it possible to use linkText locator in this code

I used  `driver.findElement(By.linkText("welcome")).click();`

But it didn't work.
Please help....

```
<div class="back-to">
<a class="button blue" href="javascript:history.back()">welcome</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @HelpingHands : Just Curious. Can you specify the reason for it's not working?

Comment: What error/exception did you get @Prashanth ?

Comment: @RupeshShinde - Sorry. I was in mistake. Actually I have written another question's answer here so.

Answer (score 1):

The **linkText** should work in this case. Or else try the below alternatives(**and please provide sufficient [implicit timeout](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits) to give selenium sufficent time to detect the element**):

**1. Using `xpath`, to click on the element 'a' with exact innerHTML/text as 'welcome':**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='welcome']")).click();
```

**2- Using `JavascriptExecutor` to click on the element with exact innerHTML/text as 'welcome':**

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='welcome']")));
```

**3- Using `partialLinkText` to click on the link with partial text 'welcome'**

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("welcome")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This Should be enough:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="button blue"]').click();
```